# How to pass state from one component file to another

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have two files signup.js and signin.js. when the user completes the login, the state isUserSignedIn changes from false to true. Now I want to display the user's data in the component Home that is in the file home.js. How can I pass the state between these components?

Comment: first in your parent componet you use the state (ex: useState), you create a function that can update your state variable, and you pass those to the childs, that's all (main idiea of the the concept)

Comment: But the component is not the child, it is in a separate file.

Comment: yes you can have child in another file , that's why there are the import insruction

Answer (score 0):

If some data needs to be shared amongst multiple components, which are not direct parent/child (I assume Home.js is not a child of others components), then you need to set up a shared state tool, like :

- Redux (https://react-redux.js.org/)
- Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)
- many others

Components local state passed through props to children is a good (and very simple) solution if components are not too far from each other (grandparent/parent) and if you don't need to share the data with another distant component.